# Moving first word to last while changing the first word to lower case

Tags: java, string

The user inputs "The car is green" it outputs "Car is green The". 
 the output should be "Car is green the".   I only help with that and I'm basically done. It would be helpful if it is possible to have the users input to be displayed bold or underlined.

```
    public class MoveFirstWordToLast{
     public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a line of text. No punctuaton please");
      String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

      int index = sentence.indexOf (' ');
      char word = sentence.charAt(index+1);

      //String change = String.valueOf(word).toLowerCase(); //uppercases the new word

      String start = String.valueOf(word).toUpperCase(); //uppercases the new word


      start = start + sentence.substring (index+2);
      start = start +" ";

      String end = sentence.substring (0 , index);
      System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read: ");
      System.out.println(start + end);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you try to change the letter to lower case? All I see is a call to `toUpperCase()`

Comment: end.toLowerCase() should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String end = sentence.substring(0 , index);
```

to

```
String end = sentence.substring(0, index).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoveFirstWordToLast{
     public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a line of text. No punctuaton please");
      String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

      int index = sentence.indexOf (' ');
      char word = sentence.charAt(index+1);

      //String change = String.valueOf(word).toLowerCase(); //uppercases the new word

      String start = String.valueOf(word).toUpperCase(); //uppercases the new word


      start = start + sentence.substring (index+2);
      start = start +" ";
      System.out.println(start);
      String end = sentence.substring (0 , index);
      end = end.toLowerCase();
      System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read: ");
      System.out.println(start + end);

    }
}
```